# How to get total count of users exclude location="Hyderabad" and include deviceBrand= "lenova"?

Tags: neo4j

I am using neo4j version 3.0.3. I have executed the below query. It is giving the results as the count of users who have the HAS_VISITED_LOCATION relation, but I want the total count of users who don't have the HAS_VISITED_LOCATION relation also.

```
MATCH (c:Consumer)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]-(l:Location) 
WHERE NOT l.AreaName="hyderabad" 
MATCH(c)-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND]-(d:DeviceBrand{BrandName:"lenovo"}) 
RETURN count(c)
```

Comment: Keep in mind your query is not doing what you think it's doing. If a consumer has visited other locations as well as hyderabad, they will be included in your first match (it will just match to one of the non-hyderabad locations). Also consumers will show up multiple times, once per non-hyderabad location they have visited, so your count will not be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

So you're asking for the count of all consumers who have the lenovo device brand and who have not visited hyderabad.

This query should do that:

```
MATCH (l:Location {AreaName:'hyderabad'})
MATCH (c:Consumer)-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND]->(:DeviceBrand{BrandName:"lenovo"}) 
WHERE NOT (c)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT c)
```

EDIT - New (but related) question on how to get consumers who have not visited hyderabad and who don't have the lenovo brand.

This new question is trickier in that it's matching on the absence of relationships.

The straight forward approach is to simply match on consumers where the consumer has not visited hyderabad and doesn't have the lenevo device brand:

```
MATCH (c:Consumer)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l:Location {AreaName:'hyderabad'})
AND NOT (c)-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND]->(:DeviceBrand{BrandName:"lenovo"}) 
RETURN COUNT(c) as count
```

While this is correct, it may not be the most efficient query.

If we look at the logical representation of what you want, we might see an alternate approach:

> NOT (visited hyderabad) AND NOT (has lenevo)

If we take the negation of your requirement:

> NOT (NOT (visited hyderabad) AND NOT (has lenevo)) = (visited
>   hyderabad) OR (has lenevo)

So an alternate query can be to find the count of the negation of what you want (the count of consumers who have visited hyderabad OR who have lenovo), and subtract it from the total consumer count to get the actual count you want.

You can try this query and see if it performs better than the straightforward approach:

```
// first get the total count of consumers, should be very fast
MATCH (c:Consumer)
WITH COUNT(c) as totalCount
MATCH (lenovo:DeviceBrand{BrandName:'lenevo'}), (hyderabad:Location{AreaName:'hyderabad'})
// union lenevo and hyderabad into one column through collecting and combining and unwinding
// (this is a workaround since Cypher can't do post-union processing)
WITH totalCount, COLLECT(lenevo) + COLLECT(hyderabad) as excludeNodes
UNWIND excludeNodes as excludeNode
// get all consumers attached to these nodes
MATCH (excludeNode)<-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND|:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]-(c:Consumer)
WITH totalCount, COUNT(DISTINCT c) as excludeCount
RETURN totalCount - excludeCount as count
```

Comment: Yes i want count of all consumers who have the lenovo device brand and who have not visited Hyderabad.

Comment: Great, the query in my answer should do exactly that.

Comment: yes your query giving the exactly results.Thank you

Comment: if I want to exclude another node in same query what i have to do?

Comment: Take a look at line 3 of my query, the `WHERE NOT...` You'd probably add a similar line underneath it to exclude relationships from the consumers to other nodes: `AND NOT ...` then append the pattern you want to exclude.

Comment: i want exclude both location and brand but it gives count is zero.  MATCH (l:Location {AreaName:'hyderabad'})
MATCH (c:Consumer)-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND]->(d:DeviceBrand{BrandName:"lenovo"}) 
WHERE NOT (c)-[:HAS_VISITED_LOCATION]->(l) AND NOT (c)-[:HAS_DEVICE_BRAND]->(d)
RETURN COUNT(DISTINCT c)

Comment: What you're asking for is contradictory. You can't get the count of users who have not visited hyderabad and both have and don't have the lenevro device brand. That doesn't make sense. Are you instead asking for the users who have not visted hyderabad and who also do not have the lenovro device brand?

Comment: i want total count of users whose location is not Hyderabad and whose device brand not lenova

Comment: Okay. Can you please edit the question description so that this is clear? Or did you actually want the answer to this question, and you're asking a new question with different requirements?

Comment: i am asking a new question with different requirements.my requirement is total count of users  whose location not Hyderabad and brand not lenova  .first we get results as some users whose location not Hyderabad.from this result i want to find count of users whose device brand not lenovo .this is my new requirement.

Comment: Got it. I edited my answer to provide both the straightforward query to this (which might not be very fast)  and an alternate query that is slightly more complex, but should perform faster.